# Can Influxfb handle 1000s of checks?

Tags: performance, time-series, monitoring, iot, influxdb

I am building an application with InfluxDB. I need to monitor sensor data from many thousands of sensors, and I need to set up alerts and notifications for each one of them. This results in several thousands of checks.

When I started creating checks, Influx started choking at about 500 running checks. Is this expected? Am I working against how Influx is supposed to be used here?

Additional info:

- My series cardinality is low, <50.
- The database in question had no actual data in it, so the checks ran on an empty database.
- Influx runs in docker, and the container went from about 2% cpu usage to closer to 400% when the checks were saved.

Comment: For clarity; is that a literal "1000s of checks (for the lifetime of the project)", or some kind of "1000s of checks per something (per second, per day, per boatload of goats sent to customers, per ...)"?

Comment: That is 1000s of separate checks, all running periodically (and on a relatively short timer, at least once per minute). So we can expect all of those 1000s of checks to be running more or less in parallel. To explain it another way: If I go to the InfluxDB UI and click on "Alerts", I would expect to see a list of several thousand entries. My guess is that this is a bad idea, but I can't find any documentation that touches on how many checks the system is designed to handle.